# operator overloading in global and element functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm new to cC++. I hope the code snippet explains well enough what I'm trying to achieve. I want a global and a element function for overloading of the < operator. In the element function the return type is bool and in the global function it is the respective type. Is this code possible to realize? (Not working right now?)

```
     class Foo{     
     //...
     //element function:
     bool operator<(const Foo& otherFoo){//implementation}
     }
     //global function:
     Foo& operator<(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& f2)
     {
         if (f1.operator<(f2))
            return f1;
         else;
      return f2;
      }
```

Comment: I'm have trouble understanding what you are asking but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask what the ability to do this would actually *solve*.

Comment: `Not working right now` - its not working because you have some obvious compile errors, you want us to fix it?

Comment: Do you want to have generalised booleans (that's the term used in common lisp for such behavior)? Treating everything except for a special value as truth value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this code possible to realize?

Yes. But you really, really, really should **not** do it! `operator<` has a very concise meaning: Is the left hand side "less" (for some definition of "less") than the right hand side?

Returning the object which is actually "less" is also a reasonable function, **but it should be named accordingly!** Call it `lesser_of` or something like that.

> Not working right now?

You did not include any useful error description in your question, but I highly suspect that the issue here is `const` correctness. You're accepting a reference to a `const` qualified `Foo` and try to call its member function `operator<` which is *not* `const` qualified. The simple fix: Add a `const` to the member function:

```
// member function:                 vvvvv
bool operator<(const Foo& otherFoo) const {
  // implementation                 ^^^^^
}
```

The supposed free (= non-member) function (which should really be called with a reasonable name, I chose `lesser_of`) can be implemented for all types with a corresponding member function, using a template:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
typename std::common_type<L,R>::type lesser_of(L&& left, R&& right) {
  using std::forward;
  // Could also use operator<(forward<L>(left), forward<R>(right)), but
  // this breaks when there's both a member function and a free
  // function available.
  if (left.operator<(forward<R>(right))) {
    return forward<L>(left);
  } else {
    return forward<R>(right);
  }
}
```

*Note that I have no idea whether the forwarding makes any sense, nor am I sure if this could lead to dangling references.*

Going a bit further, there's one kind of usage that I would consider "only just ok" if you really insist on returning "more" than a `bool` from `operator<`: In Common Lisp this is called ["generalized boolean"](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_g.htm#generalized_boolean), and basically means that anything *except* a special `nil` value is considered  to be "truthy". You could "port" that to C++ and use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++17!) to convey that meaning:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
std::experimental::optional<L> operator<(L&& left, R&& right) {
  if (left.operator<(std::forward<R>(right))) {
    return std::forward<L>(left);
  } else {
    return std::experimental::nullopt_t{};
  }
}
```

This returns the left operand wrapped in a `std::optional` if indeed it is "less" than the right. The result can be checked for in e.g. an `if` (or similar "special context") because it has [a (`explicit`) conversion member function to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool). Thus returning `std::optional` instead of `bool` won't break code that uses the comparison only where [contextual conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) can be applied. The returned value can be access by dereferencing or for example the [`value` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value).

Of course this does not allow code like `Foo c = a < b;`, but you could instead use `Foo c = (a < b).value_or(b);`.